# Triple insersection number of a surface in three-manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, homology, intersection-cohomology, poincare-duality

I heard something about the triple intersection number $\text{mod}(2)$ (but maybe also $\text{mod}(n)$) of a surface in an orientable three-manifold but I couldn't find a precise definition. My guess is the following. Consider the homology with $\mathbb{Z}_n$ coefficients, and the Bockstein of the sequence
$$
\mathbb{Z}_n\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{n^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n
$$
Given $\Sigma \in H_2(M_3,\mathbb{Z}_n)$, take its Poincarè dual $PD(\Sigma)\in H^1(M_3,\mathbb{Z}_n)$, and then I think this triple intersection number should be something like
$$
\exp{\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\int _{M_3}PD(\Sigma)\cup \beta(PD(\Sigma))\right)}\in U(1)
$$
which is an $n$'th root of unit. Is this definition somehow correct? Why is it called triple intersection number? Could somebody provide some discussion or maybe a reference. I also read that this is related with the Euler character of $\Sigma$ but I really don't see why....

Comment: You could also just evaluate $\operatorname{PD}(\Sigma)^3$ on the fundamental class, giving an integer mod $n$. Is there a reason for preferring your formula?

Comment: Since $PD(\Sigma)$ is a 1-cochain, unless $n=2$, $PD(\Sigma)^2=0$.

Comment: When $n = 2$, your integrand is the same as what Mark Grant suggested. Also note that by graded commutativity $\operatorname{PD}(\Sigma)^3 = -\operatorname{PD}(\Sigma)^3$ so $2\operatorname{PD}(\Sigma)^3 = 0$, i.e. $\operatorname{PD}(\Sigma)^3$ is two-torsion. If $n$ is odd, then we must have $\operatorname{PD}(\Sigma)^3 = 0$, but if $n$ is even, it could be non-zero (there is a unique non-zero element of order two in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ when $n$ is even).

Comment: I see. This would explain why "triple intersection". Is the formula with the Bockstein more general or not?

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is an oriented surface in an oriented $3$-manifold, then it gives an element $PD(\Sigma)$ in $H_1(M)$ (with $\mathbb Z$ coefficients). If you pass to cohomology with $\mathbb Z_n$ coefficients, this new $PD(\Sigma)$  has zero Bockstein.

Comment: If you work with $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients then you can define $PD(\Sigma)$ without requiring either $M$ or $\Sigma$ to be orientable, and you have a class $PD(\Sigma)^3=PD(\Sigma)\cup\beta PD(\Sigma)$, giving an element of $\mathbb Z_2$ that can be called the triple self-intersection number.

Comment: If you want to use $\mathbb Z_n$ coefficients with $n>2$, then you need $\Sigma$ to be orientable in order to even get an element of homology from it, and you need $M$ to be orientable in order for it to have $\mathbb Z_n$ duality isomorphism, so this will lead to zero.

Comment: On the other hand, $a\cup \beta a$ can be nontrivial, for $a\in H^1(M;\mathbb Z_n)$. If $M$ is an oriented lens space with fundamental group of order $n$, then $\beta$ is an isomorphism, and now taking $a$ to be a generator of $H^1(M;\mathbb Z_n)\cong\mathbb Z_n$ the element $(a\cup \beta a)[M]\in\mathbb Z_n$ is a generator. Replacing $a$ by $ka$ for some $k$ relatively prime to $n$ multiplies this element by $k^2$.

Comment: The geometric meaning of "triple (self-)intersection" is not necessarily what one might think. Consider the immersion of $\mathbb RP^3$ in S^3$ called "Boy's surface", with one triple point.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your first comment on the vanishing of the Bockstein of $PD(\Sigma)$. By $PD(\Sigma)\in H^1(M_3,\mathbb{Z}_n)$ I meant the result of Poincare' duality with $\mathbb{Z}_n$ coefficients, which is always an isomorphism. Did you meant a different thing?

Comment: On the meaning of "triple intersection", my intuition was that a surface in three dimensions generically self intersect in a line, and thus generically there are points with triple self intersections, and this should count them (with sign) $\mod (n)$. Is this correct?